# How to enable debugger/hot reloading/live reloading from terminal in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I know you can enable all these functionalities from in the app but for some reason my simulator wont let me click on any of them. Yes I am using the default IOS simulator so I don't think that is the issue. So does anyone know how to enable these functionalities from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately currently impossible.